# Is there an existing algorithm for finding a subset of nodes of a DAG based on path weights?

Tags: graph-theory

In this example, the outer path to the target nodes has a total cost of 5. Alternatively, the middle path (optimal) has a total cost of 4. There is no cost associated with the edge to the leaf nodes. We just want to know that they are reachable on some optimal path.

[DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oONe.png)

Comment: That drawing is of a DAG and leafs are sinks? looks like a dynamic programming approach.

Comment: I posted this same question on Quora. 

https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-existing-algorithm-for-finding-a-subset-of-leaf-nodes-of-a-tree-based-on-path-weights

Comment: @Phicar
That is correct. Thank you.